# Button positioning in relation to each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, storyboard

I have 2 buttons that I need to place in relation to each other:

[image]

The content and width of the buttons vary, so I can't just place them next to each other in storyboard. Can I use trailing or leading space in storyboard and make the relation the other button instead of the superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to do in IB -- just select both buttons and add the "horizontal spacing" option from the constraints button (the one that looks like an H) down in the lower right corner of the window.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious why you are doing this in story board. IF you need Xib's this custom perhaps you want to create an individual "test" project to work out just the view. I would highly recommend that from a software engineering standpoint, but then again I recommend against story boarding to begin with to my students for any production level project, its good for somethings but it has so many down falls as an individual developer and exponentially more down falls as a team development tool. Well end my self righteous rant.

There are three ways I can think of to solve your problem if I understand it correctly.
The problem:

- I have a view with the lowest layer being a scroll view, I have two subviews on top of it that are UIButtons.
- The buttons will vary in size due to content(assuming text/font changes, and possible pictures?).
- I want the buttons to appear next to each other in a consistent manner even though their size will vary.
- I want to support multiple orientations and possible multiple idioms.

Solution Suggestions:
1.Due to the complex nature of the problem my first suggestion is going to probably seem a little less then fun. Work out the view programatically, using relative geometric math you can solve all of your issues, it may seem daunting but it will really be the cleanest and easiest way I think by creating a custom view controller that as info updates the controller will manage the view to display appropriately, also the advantage of this is if you are really good at relative geometry your code will work across idioms.

1. Work it out with springs and struts, then test it in every way you can think of but this wont be as good as a math proof for geometry based approaches. Why you may ask, because a higher level solution does not guarantee you control. But emphasize relative resizing and positioning as you set this up.
2. This is wasteful unnecessary and will slow performance a lot, but I have had it turned in by a senior in computer science.(Poor guy never got more then 2/15 of the subjective points)

Create a view for just about every situation and have an overly complex controller switch between them. The performance costs on this are gigantic and the potential for someone finding a means to a screen that is not consistent is VERY likely.

Comment: What *are* you talking about? This is a very simple problem to solve with Apple's new layout constraint system.

Comment: THanks a lot for the elaborate answer. It ended up being as simple as making horizontal spacing on the buttons.

Comment: Simple, yes for "most" uses that would be the recommended way of doing this. However, the question posted was with the idea of variable content in the bars. When dealing with dynamic content the struts and strings can not always be counted on, especially if say the content or its format exceeds the screen limits. If my buttons dynamic content was always between 1- 9 characters I would strut spring this and never think about it again. However if I my dynamic content is 1-? I do not want "?" biting me causing for a bad app experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the class only using, just a suggestion

in .h

```
UIButton *firstButton;
UIButton *secondButton;
```

in .m

For first Button:

```
firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
firstButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 60);//this can be changed at run time
[firstButton setTitle:@"TAP1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod1)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:firstButton];
```

For second Button:

```
  secondButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(firstButton.frame.origin.x+10,    
       firstButton.frame.origin.y+10 , firstButton.frame.size.width,  
       firstButton.frame.size.height);

  [secondButton setTitle:@"TAP2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod2)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:secondButton];
```

you can put your own padding value according to need other than 10 above;
and every time your firstButton width changes just run the

```
      secondButton.frame = CGRectMake(firstButton.frame.origin.x+10,    
       firstButton.frame.origin.y+10 , firstButton.frame.size.width,  
       firstButton.frame.size.height);
```

and both will be align. i guess this helps

Comment: That would definitely be a solution, if I where to do it all in the corntroller. Would prefer to do it in the storyboard though. If it's not possible to do in storyboard, this is definitely the way I'll do it.